# Wordpress multisite htaccess

Tags: multisite, htaccess

I set up Wordpress as a multisite and as part of the steps, it gave some instruction to update and replace the .htaccess file.

Wordpress instructed me to replace the htaccess with this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

However this caused some jquery on a plugin to break.

I thought it might be useful, but could someone help provide some insight into what each of these lines does?

In particular this line:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
```

As, if I remove this line, my plugin works fine.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Is this a plugin that you wrote? A public one in the Repository? Or a premium one?

Answer (score 3):

I've been looking for details on why that line is suggested for a multisite install using subdomains as well.  I actually question if both of these are relevant for a subdomain install:

```
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
```

In a sub-directory install the rules are setup slightly different to strip the sub-directory name from the request to be something like:

```
RewriteRule  ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule  ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
```

I'm seeing a redirect loop in my error logs and it's caused by the first version of these rules since the replacement text is identical to the original text. I found some evidence that some versions of mod_rewrite will detect that the original and new text are the same and skip the re-insertion of the result.  (Not sure which of the many links I've been reading at this point.)

I see no value in rewriting a URI to be identical to original and thus causing the link to be reinserted into the rewrite engine.  With the rules removed I get the expected 404 page instead of a redirection loop that ends in a 500 server error when the redirection limit is exceeded.

Separate note, I think that the suggested sub-directory version is also broken.  Because it uses `?` for the sub-directory portion, it will loop on an input URL like `no-such-file.php`. Matching on the sub-directory portion should not allow for zero copies so the rule should likely be:

```
 RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
 RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
```

A similar conclusion is found here:  https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/73185/27576

Comment: I think that the suspect rewrite rules may exist to handle multi-site installations served from the site root, but physically located in a subdirectory (i.e. `mysite.com/wordpress` accessed transparently from `mysite.com`). If `RewriteBase` is anything other than `/`, then the rewrite engine will be using the apparently redundant rules to perform significant rewrites. I haven't confirmed this, though - still it's strange that WordPress might suggest these patterns in non-subdirectory WordPress installations.

Answer (score 2):

`RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]`
Redirects http://yourdomain.ext/wp-admin to http://yourdomain.ext/wp-admin/

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]`
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d`
Conditional logic, check if the requested filename is ***not*** a existing file (`-f`) or directory (`-d`).

`RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]`
Redirect `wp-content.ext`, `wp-admin.ext` and `wp-includes.ext` to the file itself, whether this file exists or not.

`RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]`
Redirect any `.php` file to that file, whether the file exists or not.

`RewriteRule . index.php [L]`
Redirect everything to `index.php`.

Basically, the `.htaccess` redirects every requested file to that particular file, and every directory to `index.php`.

Read over the [detailed mod_rewrite documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/) for the details of how the rewrite engine works.

Comment: Regarding the RewriteCond - It's my understanding that the `-f [OR] -d` will match if the file or directory **does** exist.  The RewriteRule on the subsequent line (`RewriteRule ^ - [L]`) would fire (`^` matches any URI) and terminate re-insertion of the URI to the engine (`-` means no substitution and `[L]` meaning this is the last rule to be applied on this iteration).